# How to read a file from dropbox c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an web page with dropbox picker. I can select a file and get the filename and link. I need to pass  this information to a C#api to read the file.

Here a snippet of my API code

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] arr;
arr = webClient.DownloadData(dropboxFileData.Link);
```

However arr contain the dropbox HTML authentication page. So, I think i have to pass the credential. How do I get this information.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers just read the API

Comment: Can you share with us the link, I may be able to provide you some really compact code if I can verify the link is in the right conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot do it with `WebClient` (it doesn't maintain cookies between redirects).

The ugly way is to use `WebRequest` to send a request, then check `ResponseUri` to determine if you was redirected to authentication page. Then you make a new `WebRequest` submitting a credentials form, get response cookies and use them for a download request once again. This should basically work, but it might break easily if DropBox changes auth form.

The correct way is to use DropBox API with [one of the libraries](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other) available. It is solid because of well documented APIs, familiar to the users, and doesn't require them to give their password to some 3rd party application.

Comment: The issue is in Javascript when the user select the button they are prompted to authenticate. Now I have the filelink and filename. So, you are saying that there is no way to get the a token (similar to google drive) and used it to get the file data. I am trying to avoid adding another dependency..

Comment: If you're using [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) dropbox picker, generated download link is not bound to authenticated account, and you may download it even on the server side.

Comment: Yes, I am using the dropdown picker. I get the filename and filelink. Now I was read the content of the file. So, I call my api and pass it the link.However, it seems to need some authentication code because I get back the login html. How do read the content?

Comment: Most likely your link is corrupted somehow when transferred from client to server. I've just confirmed that passing the direct link from picker to `WebClient` works just fine without any additional authentication required.

Comment: Thank you. I need to set it to "direct" and not "preview" link